# Java: Printing the options of a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have some code in which I ask the user for a string input which I then match against some options in a switch so the program knows how to proceed.

```
 switch (algorithm.toLowerCase()) {

        case "selection sort":
            // Selection sort stuff
            break;

        case "insertion sort":
            // Insertion sort stuff
            break;

        case "exit":
            // Default, just exit.
            System.exit(0);
```

However for a user that isn't myself, they don't know the options that they can enter. An obvious solution would be to hardcode in a print statement which tells them the options, but I was wondering if there is a programmatic way of displaying the cases of my switch before I capture the user input.

I'm thinking some sort of data structure containing the options, but I'm not sure of which way would best utilise Java and conform to its standard practices.

Comment: What is wrong with the easy way out? Just hardcode and print the options.

Comment: It *is* common in such scenarios to print a "menu" which most often is in fact "hardcoded". Mostly the user will be asked to input integers, though or at least single characters. Using Strings in switch is not that "old" in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way for your `switch` statement as is to know the options in advance, partly because you are using hard-coded constants to compare the input with.

Consider using an `enum` instead (the standard way of having limited, "hard-coded" options), and using the `switch` with your `enum`.

When comparing with a `String` such as the user input, you can invoke `valueOf`, or for values with whitespaces, you can have your own conversion methods (as variable names in Java cannot contain whitespace).

Something like:

```
enum Options {
    SELECTION_SORT("selection sort"),
    INSERTION_SORT("insertion sort"),
    EXIT("exit");
    String value;
    Options(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    static Options forInput(String input) {
        // TODO handle null/empty
        for (Options option: values()) {
            // ignoring case in comparison here
            if (option.value.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) return option;
        }
        return null; // or throw IllegalArgumentException
    }
    // minimal print of all available values as expected input
    static void printAll() {
        for (Options o: values()) {
            System.out.println(o.value);
        }
    }
}
```

... then...

```
switch (Options.forInput(algorithm)) {
    case SELECTION_SORT: {// TODO}
    // etc.
}
```

... can follow an invocation of `Options.printAll()` to display the available input options to the user.

Comment: Possible improvement: use an `EnumMap<Options, T>` where `T` is either `Supplier<U>` or `Runnable` and then populate this with lambdas. This has the advantage of `O(k)` instead of `O(n)` which would not matter for a GUI Menu, but would matter for larger `n`. Of course, the compiler could insert it into a table for you, but don't trust the compiler... Functional programming is cool yo =)

Comment: @Centril nice idea too. Probably a little overkill for this example I think :)

Comment: Looks like a great approach to handle it, I like how neat it looks in the switch and that all the options will be blocked together in the Options enum. I'll wait just a bit in case there are other answers before accepting it :)

Comment: @DanielWesleyPorteous sure! Hope it helps.

Comment: @Mena It's like bringing a nuke to a pillowfight ;) And probably some overhead for the lambdas cause this ain't `C++` so it probably won't become just an array of function pointers...

Comment: @Centril hahaha! Well it all depends on what you're trying to do I guess :D